# Show that $x\cot x = ix+2ix/(e^{2ix}-1)$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

Show that $x\cot x = ix+2ix/(e^{2ix}-1)$

So $x\cot x = x\left( \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\cdot \frac{2i}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}  \right) = \frac{ix(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}=\dots$

$\dots=\frac{ix(e^{2ix}+1)}{e^{2ix}-1}=\frac{ixe^{2ix}+ix}{e^{2ix}-1} = \frac{ixe^{2ix}-ix+2ix}{e^{2ix}-1} = \frac{ix(e^{2ix}-1)+2ix}{e^{2ix}-1} = ix+\frac{2ix}{e^{2ix}-1}$

I've tried multiplying by 1 in many different ways to try and get from $\frac{ix(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}$ to $\frac{ix(e^{2ix}+1)}{e^{2ix}-1}$ But I can not figure it out. There has to be a way, but I can't figure it out. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the numerator and denominator by $e^{ix}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$e^{2ix}-1=\cos2x+i\sin2x-1=2i\sin x\cos x-2\sin^2x=2i\sin x(\cos x-i\sin x)$$

$$\dfrac1{e^{2ix}-1}=\dfrac1{2i\sin x(\cos x-i\sin x)}=-i\cdot\dfrac{\cos x+i\sin x}{2\sin x}=?$$